# Tengo un error de tipo "Uncaught Error" en un login en php

Tags: php, html

Les comparto el codigo y el error

```
<?php 
include("ProyectoHXM/php/conexion.php");
session_start();
$error = "";
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // usuario y contraseña retornados por el formulario 

    $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
    $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']); 

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM person WHERE name = '$myusername' and contrasena = '$mypassword'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $active = $row['active'];

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    // si los datos son introducidos correctamente retornara 1 de la tabla.

    if($count == 1) {
       session_register("myusername");
       $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;     
       header("location: ProyectoHXM/index.php");
    }else {
       $error = "El usuario o contraseña es invalido.";
    }
 }
?>
```

Este es el error al ingresar

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   session_register() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto_Hotel\login.php:21
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown

Comment: Checa esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20619704/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-session-register

Comment: Que version de php usas?

Comment: De la documentación de [`session_register`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-register.php): "Advertencia
Esta función ha sido declarada OBSOLETA desde PHP 5.3.0 y ELIMINADA a partir de PHP 5.4.0." Seguramente el servidor tenga una versión más moderna de PHP (5.6 o 7) y por eso no te funcione.

Comment: Efectivamente, como dice el sr @AlvaroMontoro se ha declarado "Obsoleta"

Comment: Es php 7.2.1 la versión en la cual estoy programando

Comment: @Francisco Gracias me aclaro mi duda

Answer (score 0):

Creo que debieras empezar viendo la versión de tu php, al parecer a partir de la versión 5.4 ya no esta presenta esa función.

te dejo un link en donde lograron resolver este problema

[Solución Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082420/call-to-undefined-function-session-register)

Comment: Gracias, Ya lo pude resolver, ya que la función "session_register" esta obsoleta como me decían, lo que hice fue hacer una asignación directa así lo resolvi "$_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;"